# How to convert a class T object into a Future[T] object in akka

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am trying to do something with akka and scala and i am new to it. I want to append the result of an 'Any' Future into one of the fields in the class

So i have class called T defined as

```
class T {
  var a: String =_
  var result = List[Any]= List()
}
```

Now i have a variable which receives a future value

```
var futureResult:Future[Any] = //receives a future value
```

in a function called addResult which takes an T object and returns a future T object.

```
def addResult(obj1:T):Future[T] ={
  var obj2:T = new T()
  obj2.a = obj1.a
  obj2.result = obj1.result
  //I want to append results of futureResult into obj2.result when it is completed
  // obj2.result = futureResult :: obj2.result

  return Future(obj2)
}
```

I have to finally call this function from a flow.

```
val b = Flow[T].mapAsync[T](1)(addResult(_))
```

Comment: you can use map function on Future to change what's inside. Something like `retrieveResult: Future[Any] -> map( (result: any -> addResult: T)): Future[T]`

Comment: Calling `map` doesn't "change what's inside". It creates a new `Future`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov T is just a class name

Comment: Sorry, I thought `T` was a generic type parameter.

Comment: `T` is a very bad name for a class...

Comment: @riccardo.cardin agreed, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as @riccardo.cardin noted using `T` as a name of a class is very bad idea, because of `T` usual points to generic.
However, you can put any logic in `Future` with a simple closure, in your case, it looks like this:

```
Future {
 new T("some string", 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil)
}
```

After that, you can combine asynchronous computation via `flatMap`, `map` or with `for comprehensive` or even use `cats` [black magic](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Cartesian.html) with `|@|`:

```
for {
    f1 <- future1()
    f2 <- future2(f1.id)
} yield f2.name

(future1 |@| future2) map { _ - _ }
```

In your case this transformation depends from logic of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the commented line like this:

```
futureResult.map { res =>
  obj2.result = res :: obj2.result
  obj2
}
```

And then you won't need the last line.

Comment: I actually need the last line as it is used in a flow and the stage must be completed before next one starts executing

Comment: .. which is what happens with `map`. Btw if you intend to use the `obj2` from somewhere else (ie. not create it within that local method), you're going to have a whole lot of other issues with currency.